# Sub Query(Select Top1 Order ByDESC) not selecting 1 but returning all records in that category

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have written a query with the hopes of it returning records based on latest Date.

In this particular query I used a `select top 1, order by desc` statement. However I don't get the top 1 date, rather I get all dates.

This is my query:

```
SELECT Serial Number,
       CustomerName,
       CellphoneModel..........    
FROM CustomersTable INNER JOIN CellPhoneTables 
     ON CustomersTable.CustomerID = CellphoneTable.CustomerID 
     INNER JOIN MaintainanceTable......
     ....... AND CellphoneTables.SerialNumber IN
                          (SELECT TOP(1) Serial Number
                          FROM   CellPhoneTable
                          WHERE (CustomerID = CustomersTable.CustomerID)
                          ORDER BY MaintananceTable.CheckDate DESC)
```

These are my results::

```
Serial Number  Customers .............................. CheckedOnDate
11111                HomeCell                           1/1/2012
11111                HomeCell                           1/2/2012
11111                HomeCell                           7/7/2012
22222                BarbsConnect                       2/3/2012
22222                Barbsconnect                      18/7/2012
```

These are my desired results:

```
SerialNumber    Customer                        CheckedOnDate
11111              HomeCell                          7/72012
22222              BarbsConnect                    18/7/2012
```

I did a practice example below (which worked), so what could I have done wrong on my example above?

```
SELECT        a.AuthorID, a.AuthorName, b.ISDN, b.BookTitle, b.NumberOfPages, b.DatePublished, b.Author    
FROM            Authors AS a LEFT OUTER JOIN                          
Books AS b ON a.AuthorID = b.Author AND b.ISDN IN          
                (SELECT        TOP (1) ISDN                            
                  FROM            Books                               
                 WHERE        (Author = a.AuthorID)                        
                 ORDER BY DatePublished)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As for a given serial number you have multiple CheckDates you should select maximum date to get required records not serial number. Following query should fetch the required records:

```
select  *
from CustomersTable CT inner join CellphoneTables CellTbl on CT.CustomerID =    CellTbl.CustomerID 
inner join MaintainanceTable MT on MT.CustomerID = CT.CustomerID
and MT.CheckDate in       (SELECT TOP(1) CheckDate
                           FROM   MaintainanceTable
                           WHERE (CustomerID = CT.CustomerID)
                           ORDER BY MT.CheckDate desc)
```

Comment: Thank you that query worked now...do you mind my asking. What is the difference between selecting the serial number and the date...Seeing as on my practice example selecting the ISDN number worked?

Comment: When you select serial number for a given customer ID based on checkdate desc you get a number that have multiple matching rows in outer table. say for customer id 1 you have maximum date 7/7/2012 but you selected 11111 in On predicate so for 3 rows in outer query serial number is 11111, hence the result. But if you say - select rows in outer query where check date is maximum for current rows customer id then u will get only one row. Hope i didn't confused you much.

Comment: Because there is only one max for that match VS multiple serial numbers for that much?